# opencart pagination displaying 20 instead of 15

Tags: pagination, opencart

I have written a code for pagination in model, the query is correct which is returning 15 rows. But when we come to view, it is displaying 20 records and at bottom it is showing pagination as "Showing 1 to 15 of 15 (1 Pages)"

please help me. where I did a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are adding your code but there is option available into admin

system -> setting -> option -> Default Items Per Page (Catalog)

change option there which you want.

**Thanks**